# Member Count Channel discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

The program should work in such a way that a channel named "members" will display the number of members on the server, but the program does not give errors and does not work itself.
Thanks in advance!

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = member.guild
    channel = get(guild.channels, name = 'members')
    await channel.edit(name = f'Учатники: {guild.member_count}')


@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    guild = member.guild
    channel = get(guild.channels, name = 'members')
    await channel.edit(name = f'Учатники: {guild.member_count}')
```

Comment: do you have intents.members enabled?

Comment: btw you should consider using getting the channel with the id instead of the name, you're going to change its name frequestly so it will vary

Comment: yes they are included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I am not really sure if you have it in your program but just to be sure, define what is the attribute named "channel" so it knows what to edit, you can use `get_channel` to do it and put the channels ID afterward inside it ( https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel)
2. Maybe just try and use it the old way and use `name = "Учатники: " + str(guild.member_count)` (The `member_count` gives you an output of `int` so you may need to turn it into a string before displaying it.

(I have not tested anything and this answer is based on experience and reading documents and also you might want to take a look at https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member_count#discord.Guild.member_count)